# SELECT FOR UPDATE en PHP (en un mismo HILO)

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito hacer un `SELECT FOR UPDATE` en un mismo **hilo** con `PHP`,

Actualmente lo tengo así:

```
                $for_update = "SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV' FOR UPDATE;";
                $rs_for_update_ = mysql_query($for_update, $db);

                $sql_update_E   = "UPDATE tb1 SET ENTPROD = $CANSAL_DMV WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV'  ";
                $rs_update_ = mysql_query($sql_update_E, $db);
```

Pero necesito que sea en un mismo **HILO**, algo así:

```
                $for_update = "SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV' FOR UPDATE;
                               UPDATE tb1 SET ENTPROD = $CANSAL_DMV WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV'";
                $rs_for_update_ = mysql_query($for_update, $db);
```

Pero creo que ese, no es el sintaxis correcto.

Alguien podrá ayudarme?

Comment: en un mismo hilo, sera en una misma transaccion?

Comment: asi es, o un mismo string..

Comment: Que pasó compa, ya intentaste `msyqli_multi_query()` ?

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob no compa, no he intentado..

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob multiquery parece la solucion, queres ponerlo en una respuesta?

Comment: @gbianchi no creo que le funcione, apenas me percaté que está usando el driver `mysql` y no existe dicha función en versiones tan viejas.

Comment: esta usando el driver deprecado? entonces tal vez seria un buen momento de que migrara a un driver no deprecado.

Comment: ese driver no admite transacciones? porque de ser asi, envolver todo esto en una transaccion solucionaria el problema.

Comment: @gbianchi si lo envolvemos en una transacción, como lo harías?

Comment: mi pregunta es para que quieres bloquear la fila si la actualizaras al instante?

Comment: @Bryro porque la pueden están tomando en otro lugar....

Comment: en cuestion de microsegundos??  esto se utiliza cuando llamas a una vista y debes esperar hasta que el usuario termine de editar los campos para luego hacer el update. en este caso no te sive de nada porque la seleccionas y luego la actualizas en el mismo microsegundo!

Comment: bueno para ello tienes varias opciones como: 1. desactivar el `autocommit mysqli`, 2. crear 2 columnas `locktime` y `lockuser` y al selecionar establecer estos parametros para que otro usuario no pueda acceder a dicha fila `locktime` puedes setearlo a 5 minutos con  el  `utc+(60*5)` y el `lockuser` para saber que usuario lo bloqueo y que solo este usuario puede realizar el update los proximos 5 minutos. y asi evitas bloquear toda la tabla por 1 transaccion!

Comment: Creo que tenes un error de concepto. Si esta tomado en otro lugar, entonces fallaria el update.. o el otro lugar. Esto se utiliza para bloquear filas cuando tu estructura de tabla representa un arbol o algun otro formato de datos que no es una tabla. No tiene ningun sentido si es solo para hacer el update de esas filas en la instruccion que sigue.

Comment: @gbianchi  entiendo, por ende (según lo que dices) no existe la forma de ejecutar todo en una misma transacción, como lo muestro de la forma que necesito?

Comment: no conozco las clases de php que estas usando, pero seguro deben tener una forma de generar transacciones.. Igual lo que yo te dije fue otra cosa e iba en linea con lo que decia @Bryro.. para que querrias hacer algo asi?

Comment: ok, gracias a todos por su tiempo...

Comment: Igual, fijate como hacer transacciones con mysql (el objeto que estas usando, las transacciones deben estar en el manul) y pon la respuesta si nadie la puso antes.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob me dio una repsuesta por interno, la cual debo probar: `SELECT * FROM tb1 where CODNUE_PRO = ( UPDATE tb1 SET ENTPROD = $CANSAL_DMV WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV' )`

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93688/discussion-between-francisco-acevedo-and-gbianchi).

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93689/discussion-on-question-by-francisco-acevedo-select-for-update-en-php-en-un-mism).

Answer (score 0):

como ya se te habia explicado en los comentarios `for update`  realiza un bloqueo total de la tabla evitando los insert para otros usuarios la solucion mas simple para lo que deseas es crear 2 columnas `locktime` y `lockuser`;

```
//tiempo actual
$current_time = time();
//seleccionamos la tabla donde el locktime a expirado
$query = "SELECT * FROM tb1 WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV' and locktime < $curren_time";
```

**condicional if()** en caso de no haber resultados es que un usuario ya la esta editando y enviamos un mensaje de error!

si hay resultados continuamos con:

```
// le agreamos 5 minutos al tiempo actual
$next_time = $current_time+(60*5); // 5 minutos de bloqueo
// actualizamos el locktime y el lockuser
$update_time = "update tb1 set locktime=$next_time, lockuser=$id_user WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV'";
```

o podemos hacer solo:

```
$update_time ="update tb1 set locktime=$next_time, lockuser=$id_user WHERE CODNUE_PRO =(SELECT CODNUE_PRO FROM tb1 WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV' and locktime < $curren_time)";
```

ahora bien con esto podremos bloquear la transacciones para esta fila especifica por 5 minutos o hasta que el usuario haga el **update** y cuando nos envie los datos hacemos:

```
// agregamos el tiempo actual menos 10 para que marque como expirado
$current_time = time()-10;
// actualizamos normal 
$query = "update tb1 set locktime=$current_time, dato1 = "dato1" WHERE CODNUE_PRO = '$CODIGO_DMV' and lockuser=$id_user;
```

> **nota:** notemos que para el ultimo update no validamos el `locktime` solo el `lockuser` ya que si el tiempo expiro y otro usuario inicio la modificacion el campo `lockuser` habra sido editado por lo que no podremos hacer el update!. podremso validar con `mysqli_affected_rows` para saber si se realizo el update o no.